# Set screen resolution without monitor attached windows 10

Tags: windows-10, screen-resolution

I have 4 pcs that I want to run automation scripts on, however I only have 1 monitor and no KVM at this time.  When I disconnect the monitor my scripts fail, I can only assume it's due to a resolution change on the PC.  Is there a way I can set the resolution of the PC for when no monitor is connected or trick the PC into thinking a monitor is there when there isn't one?

I have tried a registry edit and that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: The term for such a system is "headless". You may find some google results with this. For starters you might want to go through this list: https://deskroll.com/blog/article.php?id=Remote_Access_to_a_Headless_System:_10_Things_to_Consider

Comment: I have a similar problem.

Comment: This might be a better question for ServerFault:
https://serverfault.com
Here's a similar question:
https://serverfault.com/questions/74113/running-gui-based-desktop-software-in-a-headless-vm

This URL describes running automated UI tests on a headless server using VNC to remote into the machine:
https://autumnator.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/how-to-run-remote-headless-gui-automation/